# Power in 1/2 house not a breaker?

Tags: electrical

Short out 1/2 the house when I turn on bathroom light , then if I giggle the plug of  a plugged in lamp in the living room it comes back on? Is this a wiring in house issue ? It doesn't blow any fuses power is still running threw house.

Answer (score 5):

You have a serious house wiring issue, possibly a loose wire in one or more places.

There are several possible outcomes here, one of which is your house burning down.

Call an electrician, today.

Comment: And if you can't get an electrician to come right away, turn off power at the main panel until a professional looks at your wiring.